# SOLR facet multi-level pivot on huge dataset

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I have a requirement where I need to pivot on 4 fields. Two fields contain facet values close to 50. And the other 2 fields have 5000 and 8000 values. Pivoting on the 4 fields is crashing the server.

Is there a better way to get the data?

Example Query Params looks like this:
&facet.pivot=country,state,part_number,part_code

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my question here. Please contribute if you find a better answer.
We can concatenate the fields with the highest number of facet values at index time. In this case, we could join the values of the last 2 fields having 5000 and 8000, and store it in a new field with total facets=5000x8000.

Now we can still use the pivot facet, but can limit the last field to the count we want.

Example: &facet.pivot=field1,field2,joined_field3_4&f.joined_field3_4.facet.limit=100

By this way, the combination gets lowered to 50x50x100 instead of 50x50x5000x8000.

In a similar way, you can even increase performance with more joins.
Example when you join all fields (best performance): &facet.field=joined_field1_2_3_4&facet=true&facet.limit=100